# Multiple servers with single client

Tags: c, visual-c++, winsock2

Scenerio: several servers are listening, and a single client will send a UDP broadcast to all machines on the network and the servers will reply back. (goal: get all the ip addresses of the servers)

Here is the client code:

```c
int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in connectedSocket;
    int length=sizeof(connectedSocket);
    int iResult = 0, iOptVal = 0, nOptiontValue = 1;
    SOCKET Socket;

    char receiveBuffer[1000];
    char message[1000];

    //Clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
    memset(receiveBuffer,'\0', 1000);

    WSADATA wsa;
    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("\nFailed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\n.........Initialised.\n");

    //Create socket
    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (Socket == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Create a UDP socket failed with error = %d\n" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Set socket options to broadcast
    iResult = setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,(char *) &iOptVal, sizeof (iOptVal));
    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        printf("Set socket options failed with error = %d\n" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Setup address structure
    memset((char *) &connectedSocket, 0, sizeof(connectedSocket));
    connectedSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
    connectedSocket.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    connectedSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\n\nEnter message : ");
        gets(message);

      //send the message
        if (sendto(Socket, message,sizeof(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &connectedSocket, sizeof(connectedSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("\nsendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\nMessage Successfully sent to Server");
        // fflush(stdout);

        if (recvfrom(Socket, receiveBuffer, 1000, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &connectedSocket,&length) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
           printf("\nrecvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\nServer Says : ");
        printf(receiveBuffer,sizeof(receiveBuffer));

    }

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get

> sendto() failed with error code : 10013

I look up the winsock error and it says

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. An example is using a broadcast address for sendto without broadcast permission being set using setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST).

But I am setting the sockopt to `SO_BROADCAST`. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score -1):

The relevant parts of the code you posted are here:

```c
int iResult = 0, iOptVal = 0, nOptiontValue = 1;

...

//Set socket options to broadcast
iResult = setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,(char *) &iOptVal, sizeof (iOptVal));
if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    printf("Set socket options failed with error = %d\n" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Note that the variable `iOptVal` has been initialized `0`. It's not modified anywhere else. Then you pass that variable to the `setsockopt()` function.

**This sets the `SO_BROADCAST` option to *`FALSE`*.** (Which is the default value, so actually it doesn't change the value).

It's not sufficient to set it. You have to set it to the *correct value*. Which would be `TRUE`.

You can do this by initializing the variable to `1` instead of `0`.